# How to update object properties within a reactive array in Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working on a Vue.js 3 project using the Composition API, and I have a reactive array (created with ref) containing objects. I want to update specific properties of these objects and trigger a re-render of my component when the properties change.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in arr" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
      <button @click="updateName(item)">Update Name</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, set } from 'vue';

let arr = ref([
  { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
]);

const updateName = (item) => {
  // How can I efficiently update the 'name' property of 'item' and trigger a re-render?
  // So far, to be able to trigger a re-render, I have to re-assign the array value 
  // like so : 
  let row = arr.find(e=>e.id === item.id);
  row.name = 'Object3';
  arr.value = [...arr]; //this line reassigns array value; thus triggers a re- 
                       //render however, for large arrays, this method impacts performance.

};
</script>
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you check if my solution answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you just want to edit `name` inside a very large array. I don't know how big your array is, but I'd try to pass the index to the `updateName` function like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, itemIndex) in arr" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
      <button @click="updateName(itemIndex)">Update Name</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, set } from 'vue';

let arr = ref([
  { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
]);

const updateName = (itemIndex) => {
  arr.value[itemIndex].name = "Object 3"

};
</script>
```

Other approach is to find the index and update it using the found index like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in arr" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
      <button @click="updateName(item)">Update Name</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, set } from 'vue';

let arr = ref([
  { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
]);

const updateName = (item) => {
  const idx = arr.value.findIndex(val => val.id === item.id)

  // update it using the index
  arr.value[idx].name = "Object 3"
};
</script>
```

I also see that you like to re-assign array *the react-way*. I don't know why, but you just have to update the array value and vue will trigger re-render. You don't have to re-assign it using spread operator like that

Comment: In the solution you have proposed, you are changing the object property, and this is exactly what I have been doing; however, this does not trigger a re-render; and UI is not updated. Therefore, I have to rely on the spread operator to reassign the array value; this is the only way that triggered the re-render. In some posts, this issue was solved using the "set" operator "$this.set(object,property,value); however in vue3 "set" is deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure vue not trigger re-render when an object value change ? Because it should be. My take is, you should fix those reactivity problems first, because it can make massive burden in performance by keep re-assign array like that

Comment: I am pretty sure; the UI is not changing, plus I placed a watcher on the array value, the watcher never fires...

Comment: My guess is, there's a large problem in your application ```data flow```. See this section in the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#deep-reactivity). Vue states that they will track even nested objects. Unless you're using ```shallowRef```, vue will keep track your ```ref```

Comment: @ElieAsmar This is the way it's done indeed. There's no "set" in 3 because it's not needed for such cases. You may have problems with reactivity. Consider providing a way to reproduce.

Comment: Yes, we need more of your code to find out what's wrong with your ```reactivity``` because vue ```ref``` keep track of every nested object. So you can just mutate the object directly. There's no need for ```$set``` or anything like that

Comment: watcher was not triggered, because I had to specify the {deep:true} in watchOptions parameter. As for the UI update, I am still looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#array-change-detection):

> Vue is able to detect when a reactive array's mutation methods are
> called and trigger necessary updates. These mutation methods are:

```
push() 
pop()
shift() 
unshift() 
splice()
sort() 
reverse()
```

As the object is part of the list, you can re-add it. I believe it will work

If this solution is not sufficient for your system's performance  i suggest changing your list into a key dictionary object.  Not only will your searches with id be more efficient, but you will also get this ui updates by changing attributes